# Android Test Project bigflake

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I am trying to run the example code from the [BigFlake Android samples](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/), in specific this one example: [CameraToMpegTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/CameraToMpegTest.java.txt). I am new to Android development and I am not sure how I should treat this test suite. I try to create an Android Test Project in Eclipse but it doesn't run. Examples on the Internet seems to create an Android Test Project from a specific application project. Anybody tried to run these code and can give me some hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bigflake samples were written as CTS tests, to be executed in the test harness (though some of them never actually turned into tests).  If you're not set up with a full source tree it can be difficult to get them to work unmodified.

For a complete app example, see [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).  The examples are a bit more involved, but you can get the code running more easily.  In particular, "Continuous capture" and "Show + capture camera" will be of interest.

Comment: Hi fadden, thanks for your quick reply and the hard work on grafika and bigflake

Comment: I was also inspired by grafika, and I'm currently developing a more production-ready open-source [Android video sdk](https://github.com/Kickflip/kickflip-android-sdk). I've modularized the sdk into plenty of [re-usable components](https://github.com/Kickflip/kickflip-android-sdk/blob/preview/DEVELOPMENT.md#architecture) That make using `MediaCodec` and `MediaMuxer` much simpler.